# Streaming response from nodejs server (long running task)

Tags: node.js

I am tinkering with Node and tried out code at http://pastebin.com/ESgLgjUw.  It seems like when I launch two instances of localhost:8000 (from Chrome and Safari), only the first one returns response.

Essentially, I have a long running task that keeps returning response (that needs to be streamed to the end user).  I cant use Socket.io :-(

Comment: Can you use a persistent connection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: Thanks, checked it out.  In my case, the client doesnt make additional requests.  It makes one request and expects chucked response(s) for 5 mins.  Given Node's event loop, I was thinking that setInterval approach + stream pipe would work.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: Interesting thing is that when I kill the node server, the output on the second browser window is "flushed out"

Comment: sounds like you might need to close/flush your stream from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 EventSource, it seems to be exactly what you need.

See tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

You can use SHIM to support older browsers if needed. https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource